# Yii2 - login from more database tables

Tags: database, authentication, yii2

I need a help. I have three tables (admin, teacher, student) and I want to log in them from one login form. And I need also distinguish them as roles that for example student can't go to some page as teacher. 
I created three radio buttons for every table in login form. 
Like * admin  * teacher  * student.
With using this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'role')->inline()->radioList(array(1 => 'admin',2 => 'teacher',3 =>'student'))->label('You are: ');  ?>
```

How can I make to find and log in the user when the user put there username and pass word and click on one from the radio buttons who he is? I generated three models for each table with using gii. So what and where I must write to make it work? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have table/model per each role and you want to login from the same form, then on your login form except of usual username and password fields, you'll also need a role field (some radio button where user will have to specify what role they are). Otherwise, you won't know which table to query for username/password. Of course you can query all of them step by step, but what if there are teacher or student with the same username? Username has to be something unique, if you have one login form and it is not possible to achieve in case you have 3 tables for every type of user.

Another option would be to use one User table/model for all roles by simply adding extra column `role`. I think there's `role` column inside user table out of the box if you use [Yii2 Advanced Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced). Probably this is where you can start from.

As for permission to access specific pages per role. What you need is ACL ([Access Control filter in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html)).

I found few existing articles on how to achieve what you need.

- http://yii2-user.dmeroff.ru/docs/custom-access-control - this is
  simple example
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-user-access-controls--cms-23173 - this is a bit more advanced

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Yii2 basic template. I'm new in this and I have very less time to do the project. So I need help and give me the direction. Thank you for your answer. I'll try it.